How to correctly use escape characters to write a mathematical string to a XML file using Python?
I have an XML file which I am trying to edit using Python. This is an example of the content of the XML file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NEKTAR>
    <CONDITIONS>
        <FUNCTION NAME="Baseflow">
            <E VAR="u0" VALUE="(x>3) * (y <= 3) * 4 * x"/>
        </FUNCTION>
    </CONDITIONS>
</NEKTAR>

In the original file, the value for u0 is set to 0. Using Python, I want to change this value to the mathematical expression shown in the code-block. I have tried two approaches un-successfully:

Write the in-equalities using the escape characters such as &lt; and &gt;
Try to use CDATA

What would be the right approach to do something like this using xml.etree.ElementTree ?

Show us a repex, please.

Edit
The op needs a version that doesn't escape and leave the equation as is. This can be done with string replacement by regular expressions (re). Beware that the processed string is never a valid XML and cannot be parsed by any xml package by far as I know.
import re

ORIGINAL = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NEKTAR>
    <CONDITIONS>
        <FUNCTION NAME="Baseflow">
            <E VAR="u0" VALUE="0"/>
        </FUNCTION>
    </CONDITIONS>
</NEKTAR>"""

TARGET = '(x>3) * (y <= 3) * 4 * x'

replaced_match = re.search(r'VALUE="(.+?)"', ORIGINAL)
if replaced_match:
    result = ORIGINAL[:replaced_match.start(1)]
    result += TARGET
    result += ORIGINAL[replaced_match.end(1):]
print(result)

"""
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NEKTAR>
    <CONDITIONS>
        <FUNCTION NAME="Baseflow">
            <E VAR="u0" VALUE="(x>3) * (y <= 3) * 4 * x"/>
        </FUNCTION>
    </CONDITIONS>
</NEKTAR>
"""


xml package automatically do the escaping jobs for you. Does this satisfy your need? (replace the VALUE of E tag with given equation that needs escaping)
from xml.etree import ElementTree

ORIGINAL = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NEKTAR>
    <CONDITIONS>
        <FUNCTION NAME="Baseflow">
            <E VAR="u0" VALUE="0"/>
        </FUNCTION>
    </CONDITIONS>
</NEKTAR>"""

TARGET = '(x>3) * (y <= 3) * 4 * x'

x = ElementTree.fromstring(ORIGINAL)

# find all E tags
els = x.findall('.//E')

for el in els:
    el.set('VALUE', TARGET)
x_mod = ElementTree.tostring(x).decode()

print(x_mod)

result:
<NEKTAR>
    <CONDITIONS>
        <FUNCTION NAME="Baseflow">
            <E VAR="u0" VALUE="(x&gt;3) * (y &lt;= 3) * 4 * x" />
        </FUNCTION>
    </CONDITIONS>
</NEKTAR>


Unfortunately no. I want the mathematical expression to be written as it is and not with the escape characters.

@ishan_ae OK I'll write a string replacement solution with re. Beware that the processed string is never a valid XML and cannot be parsed by any xml package by far as I know.

Thank you. Yes, your point about xml packages is true. This mathematical expression is supplied in a file and this expression, is read by a C++ application. The details of which I do not know at the moment.

Thank you. I appreciate the information and the idea. If I write the replaced string to the XML file, wouldn't it still give the escaper character error ? My goal is to modify the file with the string.

@ishan_ae Yeah, so it depends on what is your need: If you are to pass the result XML to a downstream program, then usually you should escape those characters properly like standard XML, just like the original approach. If your task is just to substitute that value by another string, you can do regexp replace, though I have no idea how doing this is meaningful.

@ishan_ae out of curiosity I googled nektar, I found out it's a cpp project that uses tinyxml as xml parser, which definitely supports the five XML entities <>&"'. So if you are working with nektar, using an escaped version would never be wrong.
